# Python Pandas Filling missing values in dataframe column with 'prefix' + respective Index numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I want to fill missing values from object column to be replaced with 'any_fixed_prefix' + '_' + 'corresponding index'.

Dataframe look like:

[image]

Required Dataframe after applying logic:

[image]

I tried several ways, but doesn't work like `fillna` or `map` method:

```
df['col1'].fillna(str(df.index))
```

or

```
df['col1].fillna('PRE_' + str(df.index))
```

DDL to generate DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', np.nan , np.nan ,'E'],
                   'col2': ['S4', 'S8', 'AA', 'EE', 'T4'],
                   'col3': [2017, 2019, 2021, 2014, 2011]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to fill NaN values in `col1`, you could use `fillna`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna('PRE_' + df.index.to_series().astype(str))
```

If you want to fill NaN values in all object dtype columns, you could use `mask` on axis to fill in with the index (as Series). This will fill NaN values `col2` in the same way:

```
tmp = df.select_dtypes('object')
df = tmp.mask(tmp.isna(), 'PRE_' + tmp.index.to_series().astype(str), axis=0).combine_first(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2  col3
0      A   S4  2017
1      B   S8  2019
2  PRE_2   AA  2021
3  PRE_3   EE  2014
4      E   T4  2011
```